# Struts persistent List

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, jstl, actionform

When someone access a web-site and logs on I load a list of descriptors from a database that is different to every user.

I want that list to be available during a navigation session. My question arise on how to pass the list to that page from struts to JSP and make it available every time the user access a certain page so on request.

I thought of using request sessions and set the list there, is that a good practice? should I what other possibilities are available in Struts 1.1 and JSTL ?

Comment: I don't do Struts, but it makes conceptually completely sense to store session scoped data just in the session scope.

Comment: still what other session scope alternatives are out there ?